# C# WPF .NET 4 - Call parent function from user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my C# WPF .NET 4.0 application, I have a listbox containing user control items. What I want is to call some functions from these user controls to the parent form.

Item user controls have binding to the listbox via view model class.

What do you propose.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a command to your user control the same way as it would be a parent view. Then you can process this command in the appropriate view model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you have a bunch of user controls and you want those controls to be able to call methods on the containing Window instance.

From inside your controls, you can use the following to get hold of the Window instance:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
```

Note though that you can't do this from the control's constructors, because during the constructor the control won't yet have a parent window and the above will return null. The best place to do this would be from the control's Initialized or Loaded events.